# Python program to find fibonacci series. More Pythonic way

Tags: python

There is another thread to discuss Fibo series in Python. This is to tweak code into more pythonic. [How to write the Fibonacci Sequence in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python)

I am in love with this program I wrote to solve Project Euler Q2. I am newly coding in Python and rejoice each time I do it The Pythonic way! Can you suggest a better Pythonic way to do this?

[Project Euler Q2](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2). Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the Fibonacci sequence which do not exceed four million.

```
fib=[]
def fibo(a=-1,b=1,upto=4000000):
    if a+b>=upto:
        return
    else:
        a,b=b,a+b
        fib.append(b)
        fibo(a,b)

fibo()
even=[i for i in fib if not i%2]
print sum(even)
```

Comment: exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python

Comment: shouldn't the definition body be indented?

Comment: Corrected. When editing, everything showed up correct, seems it was some SO formatting error.

Comment: Or some othere people that were editing it a bit later... however, it works now :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First I'd do fibo() as a generator:

```
def fibo(a=-1,b=1,upto=4000000):
    while a+b<upto:
        a,b = b,a+b
        yield b
```

Then I'd also select for evenness as a generator rather than a list comprehension.

```
print sum(i for i in fibo() if not i%2)
```

Answer (score 15):

Using generators is a Pythonic way to generate long sequences while preserving memory:

```
def fibonacci():
  a, b = 0, 1
  while True:
    yield a
    a, b = b, a + b

import itertools
upto_4000000 = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x <= 4000000, fibonacci())
print(sum(x for x in upto_4000000 if x % 2 == 0))
```

Comment: Blegh, I want to yell for the stupid use of forward-compatible code (2to3 exists for a reason), but at the same time itertools.takewhile is the right way to do it. So since the 3.x thing is a minor issue, +1 it is.

Answer (score 4):

For one thing, I would suggest summing up the terms as you calculate them rather than storing them in an array and summing the array afterwards, since you don't need to do anything with the individual terms other than adding them up. (That's just good computational sense in any language)

Answer (score 2):

I would make the following changes:

- Use iteration instead of recursion
- Just keep a running total instead of keeping a list of all Fibonacci numbers and then finding the sum of the even ones a posterior

Other than that, it's *reasonably* Pythonic.

```
def even_fib_sum(limit):
    a,b,sum = 0,1,0
    while a <= limit:
        if a%2 == 0:
            sum += a
        a,b = b,a+b
    return sum

print(even_fib_sum(4000000))
```

Comment: I prefer recursion wherever possible. ;) Isn't it Pythonic?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the fibonacci generator as in [@constantin' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578379/python-program-to-find-fibonacci-series-more-pythonic-way/578424#578424) but generator expressions could be replaced by a plain `for` loop:

```
def fibonacci(a=0, b=1):
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

sum_ = 0
for f in fibonacci():
    if f > 4000000:
       break
    if f % 2 == 0:
       sum_ += f

print sum_
```

Comment: What is the benefit to doing this?

Comment: @Asad: It is a matter of style. Some might find it to be more explicit and simpler to understand hence more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate direct method
It relies on a few properties:

1. Each Fibonacci number can be calculated directly as floor( pow( phi, n ) + 0.5 ) (See Computation by Rounding in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number ). Conversely the index of the biggest Fibonacci number less than i is given by floor( log(i*sqrt(5)) / log(phi) )
2. The sum of the first N Fibonacci numbers is the N+2th fibonacci number minus 1 (See Second Identity on the same wikipedia page)
3. The even Fibonacci numbers are are every third number. ( Look at the sequence mod 2 and the result is trivial )
4. The sum of the even Fibonacci numbers is half the sum of the odd Fibonacci numbers upto the same point in the sequence.

Point 4 can be seen from this:

```
Sum of first 3N fibonacci numbers
   =(F(1) + F(2))+ F(3) +(F(4) + F(5))+ F(6) + ... +(F(3N-2) + F(3N-1))+ F(3N) 
   =     F(3)    + F(3) +     F(6)    + F(6) + ... +       F(3N)       + F(3N)
   = 2( F(3) + F(6) + ... + F(3N) )
   = 2 ( Sum of odd fibonacci numbers up to F(3N) )
```

So convert our maximum value of 4000000 calculate the index of the highest Fibonacci number
less than it.

```
int n = floor(log(4000000*sqrt(5))/log(phi));  // ( = 33)
```

33 is divisible by 3 so it is an even Fibonacci number, if it wasn't we'd need to adjust n like this.

```
n = (n/3)*3;
```

The sum of all Fibonacci numbers up to this point if given by

```
sum = floor( pow( phi, n+2 ) + 0.5 ) - 1; // ( = 9227464 )
```

The sum of all even numbers is half of this:

```
sum_even = sum/2; // ( = 4613732 )
```

Nice thing about this is that its an O(1) (or O(log(N)) if you include the cost of pow/log) algorithm, and works on doubles.. so we can calculate the sum for very large values.

NOTE: I edited and moved this answer from a closed duplicate of this question. [Fibonacci under 4 millions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270863)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 at least if you give a generator to the `sum` function it will lazily evaluate it so there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

This is what @Constantin did and is correct.

Tested by comparing the memory usage of using generators:

`sum(range(9999999))`

compared with not doing so:

`sum(list(range(9999999)))`

The one with the generator does not cause memory exceptions with higher numbers either.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("Fibonacci Series\n")

a  = input ("Enter a nth Term: ")

b = 0 

x = 0

y = 1

print x,("\n"), y

while b <=a-2:

  b = b+1

  z = x + y

  print z

  x = y

  y = z
```

Comment: That looks more like "The most unPythonic way to find a Fibonacci sequence"!

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    num = 2

    while b < 4000000:
        a, b = b, a+b
        num += b if b % 2 == 0 else 0

    print num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```